# How many words of length $n$ over the alphabet $\{0,1, 2\}$ contain an even number of zeros?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> How many words of length $n$ over the alphabet $\{0,1, 2\}$ contain an even number of zeros?

I can't understand why it isn't $3^{n-1} \cdot 2$.

For $n-1$ letters, we have $3$ options. That means $3^{n-1}$.

And then for the last letter ($n$), we have two cases:

first - if there were odd zeros the last letter will be $0$ ($1$ option)

second - if there were even zeros, the last letter will be $1$ or $2$ ($2$ options)

means $3^{n-1} \cdot 2$

Why am I wrong?

THX

Comment: Are you asking about the number of ternary sequences of length $n$ with an even number of zeros in the sequence?

Comment: How many words of length n over the alphabet {0,1,2} contain an even number of zeros?

Comment: The number of sequences with length $1$ that have an even number of zeros is $2$.  They are $1$ and $2$.  The number of sequences of length $2$ that have an even number of zeros is $5$.  They are $00, 11, 12, 21, 22$.  Try writing a recurrence relation.

Comment: i know that the answer is 3n−1/2 but cant understand why

Comment: Your approach is correct, but you've miscounted. Let $a_n$ be the number of desired words of length $n$. Your first case then contributes $(3^{n-1} - a_{n-1}) \cdot 1$ possibilities ($\#\text{odd words} = \text{total number of words} - \#\text{even words}$). Your second case contributes $2a_{n-1}$ possibilities, so $a_n = (3^{n-1} - a_{n-1}) + 2a_{n-1}$. Can you solve this recurrence?

Answer (score 3):

OP's solution is wrong, because it is not always 2 choices for the last digit -- it can be either 1 choice or 2 choices.  All that OP's solution proves is that the answer is in the interval $$[1\cdot 3^{n-1},2\cdot 3^{n-1}]$$

Answer (score 2):

vadim123 explains why what you have doesn't give an exact formula: you don't know how often there is $1$ choice for the final place and how often there are $2$.

However, these depend on whether there are an odd or even number of `0`s in the first $n-1$ places. Write $a_{n-1}$ for the number of sequences of length $n-1$ with an even number of places. There are $3^{n-1}$ possible sequences of length $n-1$. In $a_{n-1}$ of these, you have $2$ choices for the final place to make the total number of `0`s even, and in the remaining $3^{n-1}-a_{n-1}$ times you only have $1$ choice. Can you deduce and solve a recurrence relation based on this?